# AnhkSVN Find files changed since date

Tags: svn, ankhsvn

In AnkhSVN, does anybody know how to get a list of the files changed since a certain date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but AFAIK AnkhSVN is only VS-plugin for interacting with Subversion. If you want interact with repo in more free way, you have to use standalone subversion client. IN CLI case you can use `svn log` with -r option and define range of revisions as "{DATE}":"HEAD" or "{DATE}":"{DATE}" (and beware of 1-revision-shift)

Answer (score 0):

Using AnkhSVN you can get what you are looking for. In Solution Explorer, right click on the Solution file and select 'View Solution History'.The History viewer will be displayed with all the revisions loaded. Click on the revision(s) that correnspond with the date you are intrested in and a list of the changed files will show up in the 'Changed Path' area of the History Viewer.